# Can I find something like this online?

Tags: resources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compiling documents online](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3/compiling-documents-online)

I can only use email to ask my mathematics teacher questions and that can be very unhandy. So I'm wondering if there is a site in which you can just basically paste a text written in LaTeX which then shows it as it would in LaTeX. Like a kind of google translate, but except for translating it shows the text in LaTeX. So I can mail me teacher a text in LaTeX and ask him to paste it on that site. With 'written in LaTeX' I mean just like in Math stack exchange, with dollar signs and such.

ps - you may edit the title and tags, since I don't know a proper tags/title for this question

Comment: Why don't you just attach a pdf to the email?

Comment: 1. That would take up a lot of time I guess 2. (the real reason): no idea how to.

Comment: I closed is as a duplicate, since we already have a question about online compiling, where you can read and add to. We already got 3 one-link-answers here after some minutes, no need to get a dozen more.

Comment: Check out [Auto-LaTeX Equations for Google Docs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-latex-equations/iaainhiejkciadlhlodaajgbffkebdog?utm_source=https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94372/), it does all the rendering work for you and looks great!

Comment: Zoom in on the PDF, take a screenshot. Embed the image in the e-mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://mathb.in/ would be another option. Write your code, save it and send the link to your teacher.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for sir!

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at https://www.writelatex.com/. There you can set up a document and just have to send the link to your teacher. This should be easier than copy-pasting every formula into some interface.

Comment: I still am not familair with that so it is too tough for me. What is easier is if I just tell me teacher 'go to MSE, go to 'ask a question' and paste the text in there to see what I mean', but my question was if that could be done in 1 step (so without the need for a source code and those complicated things).

Comment: @Zafar: it is that simple! You create a document there which gets a unique address and write your code in there. Then you just have to send the URL of this document to your teacher and he will see the code as well as the compiled output. I have done an example here: https://www.writelatex.com/35274wncsqb

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be [SpanDeX.io](http://www.SpanDeX.io). Here you get the possibility to invite your teacher to collaborate with you on a project. So he would be able to see the PDF output and LaTeX code and could write annotations directly into you code or use the Chat Function to inform you about possible mistakes or changes.

Also, you have the ability to use DropBox to work offline and offline.