# Is there a version management package/solution for latex? (non SVN etc)

Tags: revision-control

I'm looking for a nice versioning system for LaTeX. At home I use SVN and it's great, but some of my fellow students have a hard time just coping with LaTeX.

Is there a version management package or other easy solution that doesn't involve a server or strage programs to do the job?

It would be great if some variable was increased every time the document was compiled or something like that.

Cheers

Comment: version control can be managed by many distributed systems (git, mercurial (hg), bazaar (bzr)), etc. nothing is targeted LaTeX, but more of general use. However, many have a learning curve. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_revision_control_software

Comment: You would be better of asking this at a sister site of TeX stackexchange. Stackoverflow might be a good reference here.

Comment: Increasing a variable every compilation seems not very useful: as you need at least 2 compilations to produce a table of content and to stabilize reference, your first document will go from v1 to v3 directly... Is TortoiseSVN not enough "easy" (just point&clic)

Comment: zeroth: Yes, I'll ask there instead. Thank you
Lionell: Sure I see you point. But that could be solved by using a decimal number and a floor function, it's primitive though. I wish they would just learn to use SVN, but I've tried and failed in teaching them.

Comment: I think no need to back up every compile. Just encouraging (requiring?) them to compile often and save stable versions locally every once in a while - `mypaper01.tex`, `mypaper02.tex`, ... will develop good habits. Then graduating to svn might be easier for them.

Comment: Would an online system work? If so, there are various solutions that (claim to) integrate version control 'naturally'.

Comment: If you commit yourself to using something that's not a good, well-designed VCS, then you're probably going to be stuck forever with that poorly designed solution. Why not just use something well designed such as git, and teach your co-workers to use it through a gui? Try googling git gui.

Comment: I'll dig into this. An online system would be great, but I'm not sure if they can be trusted with my data. Git could be an alternative. Many thanks

Comment: Have a look at fossil http://fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki

Comment: @EthanBolker, with a distributed VCS (like git, hg, bzr) to commit is a _very_ lightweight operattion. I use git, and my commits often change a single line. Each one a logical (even if minimal) change.

Comment: @BenCrowell, a VCS is a tool that has many uses. Select one, and stick with that for everything (LaTeX, code, text worklogs, ...). Yes, it takes some work to get used to it, but the payoff is manifold.

Comment: As @You suggested [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27552), you could use [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/). I just mention it, because it's not the wikipedia list mentioned by zeroth.

Comment: I would stick to SVN, for beginners the most simple thing in my opinion.

Comment: A lot of alternatives. I'm open to learn new systems, but I'm only familiar with Git and SVN. Are there any especially well fitted for LaTeX?

Comment: Just my two cents: I am happy with [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org) and mercurial (`hg`).  I find `hg` commands easier to learn and keep in my head than `git` (which would technically work as well though).  When collaborating with people who don't "get" `hg`, I put a repository in a [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com) folder for them to use and commit their changes for them.  Despite not being specific for LaTeX, `hg` is pretty simple: `hg init`, `hg add`, `hg commit` are all you need to get started, then `hg push` and `hg pull` to save online.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about version control in general, not TeX.


Comment: I've closed here as this question really isn't TeX-specific, and it's also quite opinion-based (which system is accessible to others depends on them as much as the system).