# On-line LaTeX editor with Git or CVS support

Tags: editors, online, revision-control

Before I sign up to one of on-line LaTeX editors (writeLaTeX, ShareLaTeX, LaTeXLab) I was wondering if any of those support a real version control (CVS, SVN, Git, Mercurial etc). I saw that ShareLaTeX supports DropBox which can work with Git but that adds just another layer of complexity.

P.S. writeLaTeX looks really good. I wonder if they have packages like REVTeX (they should as it is now the part of TeXLive).

Edit: I just signed up for writeLaTeX. I melted when I saw vi editing mode and ability to upload my own style files.

The latest update: I quickly ditched writeLaTeX. I encountered several serious issues with writeLaTeX.

1. I could not upload an existing document. Yes there was a work around using `\input` command but the document could not been edited.
2. All documents are public by default. One needs to get paid account to get some privacy.
3. vim mode actually was not working very well.

I just switched to ShareLaTeX and so far I see no trivial issues. Yes I am using vim mode on ShareLaTeX too.

Comment: See [Simultaneous collaborative editing of a LaTeX file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27549/5764); in particular, [SpanDeX](http://spandex.io/) might be of interest.

Comment: @Werner It lookslike SpanDeX doesn't like my Opera browser? It keeps collapsing on me. Does it support Git or CVS? It looks like it supports only DropBox

Comment: The [SpanDeX blog entry for January](https://spandex.io/blog/spandex-january-scheduling-stability-support) mentions "Google Drive and Git sync support" as an upcoming feature, while the [blog entry for April](https://spandex.io/blog/spandex-update-april-18-2013) says "Coming soon, we’ll be adding synchronization between the PDF and your LaTeX source, external version control via git,...". It's actively being developed so it's in the pipes. I've never used it, so I can't tell you much more. Watch the [introductory video](http://youtu.be/aOGP5KiqGzc)...

Comment: @PredragPunosevac REVTeX is in TeX Live: I'm not sure what you mean on that.

Comment: @Joseph Wright REVTeX is American Physical Society journal class. I have published using that class and I have the papers in preparation which use that class.

Comment: @PredragPunosevac Yes, but you say 'it is not the part of TeXLive', while REVTeX is in TeX Live.

Comment: @Joseph Wright Stupid me! I meant to say that it is now the part of TeXLive. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Unfortunately SpanDex is scheduled to go away. A mail was sent by the owners a couple of days ago (May 17, 2013) saying that the site would close in 2 months.

Comment: I see that according to this: https://www.sharelatex.com/user/subscription/plans shareLaTeX is due to get explicit git support in a future version, but only for paid subscribers.

Answer (score 5):

Why dont you consider [Authorea](https://www.authorea.com/)? They implemented version control through git.

Comment: More details on git push/pull: https://www.authorea.com/issues/8 — possible but requires some low-level setup.

Answer (score 4):

Reviving this old post for anyone still looking:

Overleaf offers git support anymore. You get a git-compatible link and you can pull the project on your computer, work offline, and then push to the online editor and continue from there.

Comment: Note that this feature [will become paid](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Working_Offline_in_Overleaf) in Overleaf v2.

Answer (score 1):

The sage math cloud (cloud.sagemath.com) lets you use the terminal, and it has git installed. You still should use another host like github or bitbucket as the origin repository.

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered https://latexonline.cc/ which is an online compiler for github hosted TeX projects. You can also download and install it as a docker application. I haven't tried it yet and I'm unsure whether you can port it to support GitLab as well, but it sure looks interesting.