# Online TeX editor with Google Drive sync?

Tags: sharelatex, online

I found a mention of such a thing [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113259/on-line-latex-editor-with-git-or-cvs-support), but I still do not see anything on the web to do this.

So, is there a way to sync newly compiled TeX files in your Google Drive?

What I'm interested in is giving my students a stable url that will link to the latest version (pdf) of a document as it is being revised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution to what I am looking for.  Copying email from Henry Oswald, ShareLaTeX co-founder:

> The best option for what you want might be to publish the project as a
>   template (left hand menu) this will give you a web page with the pdf
>   you can give to the students. It will auto update each time you press
>   the publish button.
>
> Regards Henry Oswald

When opening the template in ShareLaTeX, you just click on the image of the compiled document on the left side and copy the url it generates.

The only drawback to this is that by saving your document as a template, you make it publicly available to all ShareLaTeX users - but for now I am fine with that until I am through editing/revising.  In ShareLaTeX, though, there is also an "Unpublish" option.

**UPDATE**: You need to know that in editing your document in ShareLateX, you have to "Republish" to the template, and then it will generate a new pdf which in turn gives a new url.  So I am hoping someone will provide a solution with a **STABLE URL** so I do not have to update the link every time I revise my document!

**UPDATE 2**: Sharelatex.com no longer offers this (for free anyway).  Currently using Papeeria which does exactly the trick (for free). But if you use this service you can only have one such 'public' document, which works fine for me since I'm writing a book and wanted students to have the latest edits.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [ShareLaTeX](http://www.sharelatex.com).

You can edit, compile and download your tex files on this web editor for free. It cannot support Google Drive at this moment, but if you upgrade your account, you can sync tex files to your dropbox.

I hope this will help.

Comment: Your answer is more in line with [Compiling documents online](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3/5764).