# Latex editor and online sharing

Tags: editors, online, dropbox

Are there some Latex editors that allow the online sharing? I mean an editor that when a shared file is opened by two users (for example using dropbox), each person can see on time what the other person is writing. I know that Sharelatex do it, but I would like to get an editor installed directly on my mac.

Comment: As a completely different solution, have you ever heard about [revision control softwares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control)?  They are quite widespread and editor-and-programming-language-independent.  Emacs/Aquamacs has support to many revision control systems out-of-the-box.

Comment: [Gobby](http://gobby.0x539.de/trac/) might be a solution. It's free software and platform independent.

Comment: Related: [Simultaneous collaborative editing of a LaTeX file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27549/5245) and [Compiling documents online](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3/5245)