# How to write a research paper collaboratively

Tags: collaboration

I'm writing a research paper and for that I'm using `TeX Live` and TeXmaker. Sometimes I need help (correction, improvement) from my professor. So we want a software or something, in which, if somebody edits, we can see it in real time and all edits will be updated and stored.

I don't want Overleaf as it requires a permanent internet connection to edit.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27549/simultaneous-collaborative-editing-of-a-latex-file

Comment: Real time updates without internet connection aren't possible. If you only have sometimes an internet connection, the best would be, to use version control like git. This is also a good way to see exactly the changes made by others.

Comment: You could still edit your document offline and only put it on Overleaf only when you need input from your supervisor.

Comment: As @Ingmar s link showed: set up git woth a central repository https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578289/24579 , or use github. Programmers do it all day long.

Comment: @Ingmar thanks now I'm trying to learn about git and bitbucket

Comment: @Gaussler lol actually I don't really like the UI of overleaf. I like texmaker more as it's more aesthetic. There's no problem in using permanent internet connection but maybe sometime due to power cut you may not be able to get wifi so better to use texmaker than overleaf.