# How to share a tex file for review with someone that does not know latex?

Tags: pdf, conversion, collaboration, latex-to-word

I would like to know if there are practical ways of sharing latex texts for review with people that are not familiar with latex.

Currently I use pygmentise:

```
pygmentize -f html -O full -o ./header-analysis-2015.doc ./paper-contents.tex
```

The nice thing about e.g. MS Word is that it syntax highligts the document automatically, such that the reviewer is not destracted by the latex code.

Comment: Can't you just send them the typeset PDF?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This question is very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4489/what-is-a-good-strategy-for-obtaining-comments-on-a-latex-document-from-non-late. Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: tnx. The link mentions other options but these are not optimal either. Should I include my solution in the suggested thread?

Comment: I moved my answer to the other thread. THis one can be closed.