# fancy text boxes like in Redhat documentation or mercurial book

Tags: boxes, framed

I would like to have framed texts with an Icon on the side like the ones here
http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.5/Release_Notes/ar01s06.html
or 
http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/collaborating-with-other-people.html

these text boxes are helping to emphsize text, and hg book has really nice frames around code ! which are nicer than the simple code frames I use now.

So far I found The mdframed package as a candidate for that, but the question is
how do I insert the tiny image in the side, and define internal margin ?

Can someone give a code snippet ?

** Also, another question, I love Latex, but I am thinking the following:
Since I want to publish my book online, it does make sense just to download the code of the hgbook, and learn the syntax of that XML ? would latex give me more advandages ?

Comment: `tikz` is probably your best pick to make these boxes. As for publishing online, do you mean self-publishing (createspace, lulu, etc.)? If that is the case, what is wrong with LaTeX and self-publishing?

Comment: I mean publishing online like the hgbook is published, with a website and so on... lulu and create space is publishing towards paper, and then selling online...

Comment: Take a look at [How to create PDF and HTML output from the same source](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1507/how-to-create-pdf-and-html-output-from-the-same-source) for your other question.

Comment: I'd like to know how to do this too. But I'd prefer to just use a bit of TikZ code rather than a package.

Comment: Ahlan Faheen, so when you find the code or write the code for that. Please share it with us!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think [bclogo](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bclogo) can help you. Its [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/bclogo/doc/bclogo-doc.pdf) is in french but full of examples.

Some little examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{bclogo}{Nice bclogo example}
\lipsum[3]
\end{bclogo}

\begin{bclogo}[couleur = blue!30,couleurBord=red!50,logo=\bcoutil]{Nice bclogo example}
\lipsum[3]
\end{bclogo}

\begin{bclogo}[arrondi=0.1,epBarre=0,couleur = green!30,couleurBord=orange!50,logo=\bcfeutricolore]{Nice bclogo example}
\lipsum[3]
\end{bclogo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for bclogo; brilliant!