# Idea-lamp box in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, block

I was think of making a new block (or not necessarily a beamer block) that will have the shape of a lamp, just to illustrate a new idea.

Inside this lamp, there will problably be text, that will explain the idea.

Is there a way to do that in tikz?

Are there any other ideas available on illustrating an idea in beamer?

[image]

Comment: Not so spectacular like your bomb, but `bclogo` can help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16225/1952

Comment: May be you want to use [`shapepar`](http://ctan.org/pkg/shapepar). Some nice examples: [Fitting text to a shape in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67032/1952)

Answer (score 5):

I saved your image as `idea.png` (any bulb image will do) and then I inset text over it, using the specified size of the idea to determine the vertical and horizontal offsets, as well as the width of the `\parbox` inset.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,stackengine}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\newlength\ideawidth
\def\defaultideawidth{3in}
\newcommand\idea[2][\defaultideawidth]{%
  \setlength\ideawidth{#1}%
  \stackinset{c}{-.02\ideawidth}{c}{.08\ideawidth}{\parbox{.3\ideawidth}{#2}}{%
  \includegraphics[width=\ideawidth]{idea}}
}
\begin{document}
\idea[1.7in]{This is my idea!}

\idea[4in]{\LARGE This is also my idea!}

\idea[4in]{\small This is an idea that takes a lot of words to explain and so
  I must use a smaller font!}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Doing it in `beamer` is no problem, though a few defaults and offsets might want to be changed, to match the default sans serif font:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newlength\ideawidth
\def\defaultideawidth{3in}
\newcommand\idea[2][\defaultideawidth]{%
  \setlength\ideawidth{#1}%
  \stackinset{c}{-.02\ideawidth}{c}{.06\ideawidth}{\parbox{.3\ideawidth}{#2}}{%
  \includegraphics[width=\ideawidth]{idea}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\idea[1.7in]{\small This is my idea!}
\idea[2.2in]{This is also my idea!}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\idea[3.5in]{\small This is an idea that takes a lot of words to explain and so
  I must use a smaller font!}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Two possibilities with `tcolorbox` *a la beamer* boxes:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{ideabox}[2][]{colback=yellow!15!white, colframe=red!75!black, 
        fonttitle=\bfseries, beamer, watermark graphics=Lamp.png,
        watermark opacity=.5, title=#2, #1}

\newtcolorbox{anotherideabox}[2][]{colback=yellow!15!white, colframe=red!75!black,
        fonttitle=\bfseries, beamer, title=#2, #1, 
        sidebyside, righthand ratio=.3}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Some ideas with \texttt{tcolorbox}}
\begin{ideabox}{Lamp as watermark}
\lipsum[2]
\end{ideabox}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Some ideas with \texttt{tcolorbox}}
\begin{anotherideabox}{Lamp in \texttt{tcblower}}
\lipsum[2]
\tcblower
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Lamp.png}
\end{anotherideabox}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A little different...

[image: what's new?]

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{rgb,x11names,svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz,multi,varwidth,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(n.north)]
  \node (n) [starburst, fill=DarkViolet, draw=cyan, line width=2pt, font=\bfseries\sffamily, text=cyan, align=center] {NOW\\in LATIN!!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(n.center)]
  \node (n) [starburst, fill=Gold, draw=WildStrawberry, line width=2pt, font=\bfseries\Large\sffamily, text=WildStrawberry] {NEW!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```